# Title shown in Google search is not complete

Tags: discussion, bug, questions

If I search Google for "apple cider vinegar for heartburn" or "apple cider vinegar for acid reflux", [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5026/155) doesn't show up in any of the first 10 pages of Google results.

If I search specifically for that question, I find this:

[image: 2017-10-20 apple cider vinegar for heartburn skeptics - Google Search]

The truncated title `Is acid reflux ("heartburn")` is nonsensical.  Is that affecting the results?

For comparison, if I search for "cramps caused by Lactic Acid", this question is the 5th result:

[image: 2017-10-20 cramps caused by Lactic Acid - Google Search]

The title is complete and doesn't waste space saying "Stack Exchange".

Is there a way to improve how our questions show up in search results?

Comment: This seems to be a problem network-wide. [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mIC2.png), which is the search result for [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/320911/191178). It's even dumber than your examples because it literally cut off the last 4 characters. However, in some searches it displays the whole title.

Comment: I'd wager that Google has some algorithm that performs some kind of optimization on which words are most relevant in the title. Though, I imagine it can be overridden for a price.

Comment: Bing displays a little more of the title--which seems to support my theory.

Comment: Bing shows `Is acid reflux ("heartburn") caused by having ... - Skeptics`

Comment: I guess I'm not being fair in my search comparison, though, since my question doesn't contain "Apple cider vinegar" in the title